# Como alterar os últimos 100 registros da tabela no banco de dados PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu preciso alterar um campo da tabela na minha base de dados para realizar alguns testes, e gostaria de atualizar somente os 100 últimos registros da tabela. Eu já tentei esse código:  `UPDATE titulo SET autorizado='S' ORDER BY id_titulo DESC LIMIT 100;`  Mais esse código me retorna um erro no `ORDER` que não consegui entender o por que. Se alguém tiver alguma outra alternativa de como fazer isso e quiser compartilhar eu agradeço desde já se puder me ajudar.

Comment: Diga qual é o erro.

Comment: ERRO: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "ORDER"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 34

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operações `UPDATE` não recebem parâmetros `ORDER BY`. Você precisa selecionar os registros primeiro:

```
UPDATE titulo SET autorizado='S' WHERE id_titulo IN
(SELECT id_titulo FROM titulo ORDER BY id_titulo DESC LIMIT 100);
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente! vlw.

Comment: @BrunoDuarte Não por isso, é sempre um prazer ajudar!

Answer (score 2):

O `UPDATE` não tem `LIMIT` então ele acha que aquilo é continuidade do `ORDER BY` que também não é aceito.

Tenta isto:

```
UPDATE titulo SET autorizado = 'S' FROM (
    SELECT id_titulo FROM titulo ORDER BY id_titulo DESC LIMIT 100 FOR UPDATE) subquery
    WHERE id.titulo = subquery.id_titulo;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/Filter.sql).

Isto fará a seleção que deseja e aplicará a atualização nela.

O `FOR UPDATE` pode ser descartado se não precisar de concorrência. Só faça isto se tiver certeza que não haverá problema.